# Publish Facebook POST Using API not Considering OG Meta Tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, publish, metatag

in my website i save the new pages & automatically publish that page in in my facebook page using [this facebook link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed#publish), but after publish if i want to normally share this post and put the url i get no title or image or .. when i go to facebook [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and enter that url i realize that it doesn't read the og tags, but if i click "Fetch new scrape information" it get the information from og tags correctly. what is the problem and how can i solve it?

below is the PHP code function i used:

```
function facebook_post($fb_data) {
    $config = array('appId' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET);
    $fb = new Facebook($config);
    $fb->setAccessToken(FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN);
    $post_access_token = FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    $page_info = $fb->api("/" . FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID . "/?fields=access_token", 'GET', array('access_token' => FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN));
    $post_access_token = $page_info['access_token'];
    //
    $params = array(
        "access_token" => $post_access_token
        //, "message" => $fb_data['facebook_message']
        , "link" => $fb_data['facebook_url']
        , "picture" => $fb_data['facebook_image']
        , "name" => $fb_data['facebook_title']
        //, "caption" => $fb_data['facebook_caption']
        , "description" => ($fb_data['facebook_description'] ? $fb_data['facebook_description'] : '')
        //, "published" => true
    );
    // post to Facebook : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/
    try {
        $ret = $fb->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $params);
//        $post_id = $ret['id'];
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a link to a newly created page you did not fetch new scrape information yet.

Comment: You need to make Facebook scrape your new pages at least once, so that it can cache the OG meta data. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects#update

Comment: i already fetch it with scrape=true but the same.. this is a url page example [http://www.saidacity.net/news/212817/%D9%82%D9%88%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%85%D9%86--%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D9%82%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%81-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AD%D9%82%D9%84-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D9%82-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A5%D8%AB%D9%86%D9%8A%D9%86]